# Why does she give birth to a dog-headed baby?

Tags: the-childs-eye

In [The Child's Eye (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1314170/), why does Chuen's wife give birth to a dog-headed baby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a point in the movie where Rainie Yang's character says that the worst thing a pregnant woman can do is kill something, then she kills a cockroach. There are many Chinese superstitions about pregnant women that suggest killing or harming an animal will result in the baby looking like that animal. Chuen's wife killed the dogs, so she has a dog-faced baby.

The best plot explanation I found is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/vinnyreview/reviews-2012/the-child-s-eye) and accounts of Chinese pregnancy superstitions are [here](http://www.4panda.com/chinatips/culture/baby.htm) (and many other sites as well).